# How do I use the aggregate function to mean|count|sum up multiple columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `Donations` which has the following columns:

```
head(Donations)
Gender  $inYear04  $inYear05  $inYear06
M        19000      25000      7000
F        17000      15000      12000
F        10000      14000      10500
M        12000      19000      8000
M        2000       11000      18000
F        10500      16000      19500
```

Following is the desired output:

```
Gender Count Percentage_Count Total_Donation  Percentage_Donation Mean_Donation
   M    51         0.5           500000          0.38                7000
   F    49         0.5           800000          0.61                9000
```

The output column labels are derived by using operations in columns `$inYear04`,`$inYear05` and `$inYear06`.

Is `aggregate()` the best way to proceed with?

PS:I am new to R programming

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Gender) %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(), Percentage_Count = n() / nrow(.), 
            Total_Donation = sum(value),
            Percentage_Donation = sum(value) / sum(.$value), 
            Mean_Donation = mean(value))
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Gender Count Percentage_Count Total_Donation Percentage_Donation Mean_Donation
#  <fctr> <int>            <dbl>          <int>               <dbl>         <dbl>
#1      F     9              0.5         124500           0.5071283      13833.33
#2      M     9              0.5         121000           0.4928717      13444.44
```